# Eigrp flapping while using natting with route map

Tags: cisco, ip, troubleshooting, eigrp

I have configured a topology which contains ip sla , route map , dual natting.It work perfect but when I used route map  natting the eigrp become flapping and show the error is "retry limit exceeded".
[image: as shown in this image]

Comp_R:
configured Eigrp 10 between Comp_R and Tel_isp to reach to 1.1.1.0 network on Tel_isp interface f1/0.
configured ip sla on Comp_R Router to track 1.1.1.1 if down then it will revert to Zon_isp.
configured natting using route map on Comp_R Router.

```
 configuration on Comp_R Router:

 Comp_R (config)#Router eigrp 10
       Network 10.0.0.0
       Passive-interface f0/0 //no to send update on f0/0 

   Configure Ip sla and track 

      Comp_R(config)#ip sla 10
      Comp_R(config-ip-sla)#icmp-echo 1.1.1.1 source-ip 10.0.0.1
      Comp_R(config-ip-sla-echo)#frequency 5
      Comp_R(config-ip-sla-echo)#timeout 5000 
      Comp_R(config)#ip sla schedule 10 start-time now life forever

  Now configure track

     Comp_R(config)#track 15 ip sla 10 reachability 

    Comp_R(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.2 track 15
    Comp_R(config)#ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 20.0.0.2 10

 Configure Nat on Comp_R using route map

    Comp_R(config)#int f0/0 
    Comp_R(config-if)#ip nat outside 
    Comp_R(config-if)#exit
    Comp_R(config)#int f1/0
    Comp_R(config-if)#ip nat outside 
    Comp_R(config-if)#exit
    Comp_R(config)#int f2/0
    Comp_R(config-if)#ip nat inside 
    Comp_R(config-if)#exit

    Comp_R(config)#route-map natfortelisp permit 10 // route map name your choice
    Comp_R(config-route-map)#match interface f0/0
    Comp_R(config-route-map)#exit
    Comp_R(config)#route-map natforzonisp permit 10
    Comp_R(config-route-map)#match interface f1/0
    Comp_R(config-route-map)#exit
    
    Comp_R(config)#ip nat inside source route-map natfortelisp interface f0/0 overload 
    Comp_R(config)#ip nat insdie source route-map natforzonisp interface f1/0 overload 



 configuration on Tel_isp Router:

 Tel_isp(config)#Router eigrp 10
       Network 10.0.0.0
       Network 1.1.1.0
     No auto-summary
```

Problem create when configured route map and eigrp show the following message

```
Comp_R#
*May  3 07:34:40.059: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 10: Neighbor 10.0.0.2 (FastEthernet0/0) is up: new adjacency
*May  3 07:35:59.579: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 10: Neighbor 10.0.0.2 (FastEthernet0/0) is down: retry limit exceeded
*May  3 07:36:01.887: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 10: Neighbor 10.0.0.2 (FastEthernet0/0) is up: new adjacency
*May  3 07:37:21.407: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 10: Neighbor 10.0.0.2 (FastEthernet0/0) is down: retry limit exceeded

  checking Comp_R routing table it shows:

    Comp_R#sh ip eig nei
    EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(10)
    H   Address                 Interface              Hold Uptime   SRTT   RTO  Q  Seq
                                               (sec)         (ms)       Cnt Num
    0   10.0.0.2                Fa0/0                    13 00:00:46    1  5000  1  0

  Tel_isp Routing table:

  Tel_isp#sh ip ei nei
   EIGRP-IPv4 Neighbors for AS(10)
```

what I misconfigured,I am using eve-ng

Comment: You cannot NAT EIGRP (or most routing protocols). EIGRP uses multicast (224.0.0.10) and its own transport protocol (88), but NAT does not work well with multicast, and it only works with TCP, UDP, and ICMP. If you need to use EIGRP across a NAT connection, then you need to use a tunnel that supports multicast, e.g. GRE.

Comment: if i use port forwarding which declare that forward 10.0.0.0 network without NAT because I advertise 10.0.0.0 in eigrp

Comment: You need to use a tunnel to have EIGRP work correctly across a NAT. It is pretty simple. The tunnel packets will be carried across the Internet, and the two sites see the tunnel as a directly connected point-to-point link.

Comment: I don't like to ,to use eigrp but there is no other way to reach to 1.1.1.1 to monitor ip sla readability.

Comment: This looks like [an X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369973). You should ask a question about the actual problem, not your proposed solution. You cannot actually run EIGRP across the public Internet. You really need to establish a tunnel to connect the two sites, then there are methods you can use for IPSLA monitoring, and you may not need EIGRP, but we would need to see the configurations to help with that.

Comment: My question is how to configured dual nat for two isp using route map and also to  use ip sla as shown in the above question image.

Comment: but ip sla should be configured to indirect link

Comment: ISPs do not use NAT. They use public IP addresses that are directly connected, and they use BGP for the public Internet. Some ISP customers use NAT to connect private addressing to the ISPs public network, but that breaks things like EIGRP, which is why businesses use tunnels between sites or for extranets to other businesses across the public Internet. You cannot multicast on the public Internet, or use protocols other than TCP, UDP, or ICMP through NAT. EIGRP uses a link-local multicast, so it requires a direct connection, e.g. a tunnel.